# Does kendo listview has limit on amount of data that it can display?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have more than 50000 dataitems that I want to load in a kendo listview with a datasource and JSON call. I observed when the data size is small ( ex- 1000 list items) I am able to display the data and use a pager to scroll through the records. However, when the datasize is large ( more than 50,000 items) the datasource times out and does not display any data at all. What is the workaround to resolve this performance issue? I am using IIS express with Kendo for UI & MVC for server side development.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to display 50k items without paging the data? That's quite a bit of data and DOM manipulation; will every user view all of that data?